# Converting JSON object from requests.get() to dict

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm pulling a json object from a url:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://my.endpoint.com/Hardware.json')
```

Now I need to convert this from `r.json()` to a `dict`, so that I can insert it as a document to MongoDB (I think. I'm new to Mongo, soo).

When I try:

```
import json
d = json.loads(r.json())
```

It fails with:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Ultimately, I just want an object type that I can pass into `MongoClient().test.hosts.insert_one()` as a new document, from `pymongo`.

Comment: r.json() already is a dict. There is no need in converting it

Comment: Hm, so why do I get `TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON...` when I try passing just `r.json()` into `insert_one()` from pymongo?

Comment: can you print the type(r.json())?

Comment: `<type 'list'>`

Comment: Then you have a list. If you want to insert a list of documents you have to use the insert_many() method from pymongo

Comment: Ah, of course! Mind compiling your responses to an answer, so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`r.json()` can return a `dict` or a `list` so there's no need to convert it to JSON.

If it is a dict then `insert_one()` should work just fine but if it is a list then you need to use `insert_many()` method instead.